# How can i get images from an an API through JSON or recommend me a better way

Tags: java, android

I am getting response from cricinfo api in a listview but these are only strings i am not able to get image for every newsfeed. You can see imageview as like dots above every layout in listview. 
[image]

here is my code.

```
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("articles");

                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String author = c.getString("author");
                    String title = c.getString("title");
                    String decpn = c.getString("description");
                    String date=c.getString("publishedAt");
                    String image=c.getString("urlToImage");


                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> news = new HashMap<>();

                    news.put("author", author);
                    news.put("title", title);
                    news.put("publishedAt" , date);
                    news.put("description", decpn);
                    news.put("urlToImage" , image);

                    newslist.add(news);
```

Comment: Have you used an imageView to render images from api?

Comment: Can you show the JSON response?

Comment: from api you get url for the image and then load it using image loaders like glide or picasso

Comment: i have used image variable in picasso but it says"you have to write url"

Comment: i dont want to write url bcoz  i want different photos for every layout newsfeed

Comment: Please show your json response..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

```
Picasso.with(this)
   .load(newslist.get(i).get("urlToImage")//YOUR IMAGE URL HERE)
   .into(yourImageView);
```

**OLD**

You need to load image in your ImageView. What you are getting in response from cricinfo is image's URl. So load this URL into ImageView using [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Volley's NetworkImageView](https://github.com/google/volley).

Comment: brother i have used this library. see my code i am getting urlToImage in a variable i am not able to write it in picasso.url required

Comment: solve my problem i will accept your answer

Comment: Can you please show what value you get in your "urlToImage "?

Comment: Image File name like.. url/image.jpg

Comment: "urlToImage": "http://www.espncricinfo.com/db/PICTURES/CMS/266200/266249.1.jpg",

Comment: This is just a normal image URL so it can be load easily with Picasso or any other library. See my updated answer. Let me know if any doubts.

Comment: actually problem is, my app crashes when i write picasso in my json code. like.    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(image).into(img);

Answer (score 1):

To load image ,Please use the third party library like
' Picasso.with(context)
         .load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEIKP.jpg")
    .into(image_View);' 
it is  easy to load the your image.

Answer (score 1):

So what are you using to download the actual image?
I suggest using either [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) (I prefer this one) or [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) libraries to do it. Both are very easy to use. They will download an image and put it into the view, they will also handle caching.

Comment: brother i have used this library. see my code i am getting urlToImage in a variable i am not able to write it in picasso..